# http authentication not redirecting

Tags: php, http, authentication

I just moved this site from one server to an another. It was working perfectly fine on DigitalOcean then was moved to SiteGround. Now the login is not working, they took a look and said this was the issue but this was working perfectly fine before.

```
class AmbushController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
public function init()
{        
    //PROTECT PAGE WITH HTTP AUTHENTICATION
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Please enter admin password"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo 'Unauthorized';
        exit;
    } else {
        if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] === 'user' &&
            $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] === 'pw'){
        } else {
            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
            echo 'Unauthorized';
            unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
            exit;
        }
    }
    $this->_helper->layout->setLayoutPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/scripts/admin/');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting display php errors on and and seeing what the output is?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there's not any output before header is called? Blank spaces often cause insidious issues.
If this code worked fine on the former server, you could take a look at configuration files, but personally I should take a look at php.ini :-)